# How to see the compression used to create a parquet file with pyarrow?

Tags: pyarrow

If I have a parquet file I can do

```
pqfile=pq.ParquetFile("pathtofile.parquet")
pqfile.metadata
```

but exploring around using `dir` in the `pqfile` object, I can't find anything that would indicate the compression of the file.  How can I get that info?

Comment: `pqfile.metadata.to_dict()` will show you a lot more information including compresssion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@0x26res has a good point in the comments that converting the metadata to a dict will be easier than using dir.

Compression is stored at the column level.  A parquet file consists of a number of row groups.  Each row group has columns.  So you would want something like...

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pa.Table.from_pydict({'x': list(range(100000))})
pq.write_table(table, '/tmp/foo.parquet')
pq.ParquetFile('/tmp/foo.parquet').metadata.row_group(0).column(0).compression
# 'SNAPPY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the parquet file, an easy way to check all columns in each row group is this:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

compression_codecs = set([])
parquet_metadata = pq.ParquetFile('./your_file.parquet').metadata
for i in range(parquet_metadata.num_row_groups):
    for j in range(parquet_metadata.num_columns):
        compression_codecs.add(parquet_metadata.row_group(i).column(j).compression)

print(f'Compression codecs used in the parquet file: {compression_codecs}')
```